# Verifying uniform convergence of $\left \{f_n(x)\right \}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A sequence of functions $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ converge pointwise on $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e.$f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$ exists for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$).

Assuming that $$\sup_{k\ge n,x\in[-n,n]}|f_k(x)-f(x)|\le\frac{1}{n} ,$$can we prove

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=0\quad ?$$

---

Supposing $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\ne0 ,$ then for any positive integer $n$ and a fixed sufficiently small positive number $\varepsilon_0$,there is  a $x_{n}\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f_{n}(x_n)-f(x_n)|＞\varepsilon_0.$Since $\sup_{k\ge n,x\in[-n,n]}|f_k(x)-f(x)|\le\frac{1}{n},$ when $n$ large enough$(n＞\frac{1}{\varepsilon_0}),$$x_{n}\notin[-n,n].$ But how to go further?

Comment: As for your argument, you probably want to make sure $n > \max \{\frac{1}{\epsilon_{_0}}, x_n\}$.
Also perhaps to add some clarity to your argument, maybe say $x_0$ or something instead of $x_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }-n\le x\le n\\ 0&\text{if }x<-n\lor x>n\end{cases}$. You have $\sup\limits_{k\ge n,\, x\in [-n,n]}\lvert f_k(x)-f(x)\rvert=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert=1$.

Same idea for $C^\infty$ functions such as $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }\lvert x\rvert\le n\\ 0&\text{if }\lvert x\rvert>n+\frac1n\\ \left(\int_0^{1/n}e^{(nt(nt-1))^{-1}}\,dt\right)^{-1}\int_{0}^{x+n+n^{-1}} e^{(nt(nt-1))^{-1}}\,dt &\text{if }-\frac1n -n < x<-n\\  1-\left(\int_0^{1/n}e^{(nt(nt-1))^{-1}}\,dt\right)^{-1}\int_{0}^{x-n} e^{(nt(nt-1))^{-1}}\,dt &\text{if }n < x<n+\frac1n\end{cases}$$